# Do we have to use `CompareExchange` rather than `Exchange` in a hybridLock lock that uses AutoResetEvent?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr

The example below is from CLR via C# book that mimic a hybrid lock:

```
internal sealed class AnotherHybridLock : IDisposable 
{
   // The Int32 is used by the primitive user-mode constructs (Interlocked methods)
   private Int32 m_waiters = 0;

   // The AutoResetEvent is the primitive kernel-mode construct
   private AutoResetEvent m_waiterLock = new AutoResetEvent(false);

   // This field controls spinning in an effort to improve performance
   private Int32 m_spincount = 4000; // Arbitrarily chosen count
   
   // These fields indicate which thread owns the lock and how many times it owns it
   private Int32 m_owningThreadId = 0, m_recursion = 0;

   public void Enter() {
      // If calling thread already owns the lock, increment recursion count and return
      Int32 threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
      if (threadId == m_owningThreadId) { 
        m_recursion++; 
        return; 
      }

      // The calling thread doesn't own the lock, try to get it
      SpinWait spinwait = new SpinWait();
      for (Int32 spinCount = 0; spinCount < m_spincount; spinCount++) {
         // If the lock was free, this thread got it; set some state and return
         if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_waiters, 1, 0) == 0) // <-----------------here
            goto GotLock;

         // Black magic: give other threads a chance to run in hopes that the lock will be released
         spinwait.SpinOnce();
      }

      // Spinning is over and the lock was still not obtained, try one more time
      if (Interlocked.Increment(ref m_waiters) > 1) {
         // Still contention, this thread must wait
         m_waiterLock.WaitOne();   // Wait for the lock; performance hit
         // When this thread wakes, it owns the lock; set some state and return
      }

       GotLock:
           // When a thread gets the lock, we record its ID and indicate that the thread owns the lock once
           m_owningThreadId = threadId; m_recursion = 1;         
   }

   public void Leave() {
      // If the calling thread doesn't own the lock, there is a bug
      Int32 threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
      if (threadId != m_owningThreadId)
         throw new SynchronizationLockException("Lock not owned by calling thread");

      // Decrement the recursion count. If this thread still owns the lock, just return
      if (--m_recursion > 0) return;

      m_owningThreadId = 0; // No thread owns the lock now

      // If no other threads are waiting, just return
      if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_waiters) == 0)
         return;

      // Other threads are waiting, wake 1 of them
      m_waiterLock.Set(); // Bad performance hit here
   }

   public void Dispose() { m_waiterLock.Dispose(); }
}
```

I can understand how the `AnotherHybridLock` works but have a question on this line:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_waiters, 1, 0) == 0) 
  goto GotLock;
```

can we use `Exchange` as:

```
if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_waiters, 1) == 0) 
  goto GotLock;
```

as it looks a little bit simple, I mean if `ref m_waiters` is already 1, there is no harm to "overwrite" it to 1 again.

I understand that to be rigorous in the logic, `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_waiters, 1, 0) == 0` is correct, but I want to make sure `Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_waiters, 1) == 0` also works, so that I know my understanding on the usage of `Interlocked` methods is correct

Comment: What is a hybrid lock? How it differs from a non-hybrid lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Yes".

From this operation:

```cs
Interlocked.Increment(ref m_waiters)
```

we know `m_waiters` could be `2`, `26`, or something else. We don't want to lose that value by blindly stomping it to `1`. The CEX is purely to do something special in the "we're the first waiter" scenario, and that requires CEX.

If the field was only ever `0` or `1`, then we *might* be able to switch. Alternatively, we could perhaps *just* use an interlocked increment, and not use either exchange or compare-exchange.